# How I play Minecraft in fullscreen but keep my taskbar?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Minecraft crashed so I loaded it back up and now my taskbar is gone. I could not maximize/minimize my window. How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you in fullscreen mode?

Comment: ya but before I was in fullscreen and it still showed my taskbar and allowed me to minimize/maximize

Answer (score 1):

I use a Windows launcher for Minecraft and set the game window size slightly smaller than the size of the screen. Then configured the Windows task bar to autohide.

The game window starts centered, so I have almost all the screen space dedicated to MC. In game, I can press the Escape key to free the mouse and go for the taskbar (that shows when the mouse cursor is almost in the lower limit of the screen) and easily change to another window or even click in the MC button in the taskbar to minimize the game.

If/when the game crashes for any reason, I am not locked in the caves :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that if you're in fullscreen mode, you won't be able to access your taskbar or maximize/minimize your window. If you could before, that was probably a bug which resolved itself once you restarted the launcher. Disabling fullscreen mode will fix it. If you want to keep fullscreen mode but still be able to access other windows, you can press alt+tab to switch to other windows.

Comment: so when I press alt tab by the way I tried that and it crashed my game so ya idk how but ya

Comment: and even if I exit fullscreen it still doesn't do anything

Comment: by the way its modded minecraft

Comment: If it's modded minecraft, I can't help you. It's probably due to one of the mods you downloaded conflicting with Minecraft's code.

Answer (score 0):

I have played Minecraft for a very long time and as far as I know its not possible to go fullscreen with your task bar still showing.